# Relations between tables in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, associations

I need help with creating the right relations between 3 tables in CakePHP. These are:

1. users - pK = user_id
2. books - pK = book_id
3. books_users

I am trying to make my users_books-table contain all the relations between what book belongs to what user, and vica versa, like:

```
ID  |  user_id  |  book_id
--------------------------
 1      321          231
 2      24           58
 3      80           58
 4      24           75
 5      80           231
```

My approach has been to make a hasAndBelongsToMany-relation, but when adding a new book the users_books-table does not get populated with any info.

In my controller I've tried the saveAll() and saveAssociated()-method but nothing works.

Can anybody help me with what association-code i should put in my Models to make this work?

```
public function addBook() {
    $this->Book->create();

    $this->request->data['Book']['book_user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('user_id');
    $data = $this->request->data['Book'];

    if (!$data['book_img']['name']) {
        unset($data['book_img']);
    }

    if ($this->Book->saveAll($data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The book has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The book could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

The the new array:

```
$test = array('User' => $this->Auth->user('user_id'), 'Book' => $data);
pr($test);
```

Outputs this:

```
Array
(
[User] => 4
[Book] => Array
    (
        [book_study_id] => ha_fil
        [book_title] => The title
        [book_price] => 123
        [book_isbn] => 123
        [book_user_id] => 4
    )
```

)

Thanks in advance, Jesper.

Comment: put your `view` and `controller` code also

Comment: @Anilkumar i've added how my controller action looks, but is it relevant how my view look?

Comment: [Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)... **Table names are in alphabetical order *by convention*. It is possible to define a custom table name in association definition.**

Comment: Sorry @Nunser this was a mistake made by me when writing the question. the table is called books_users originally, and has been edited now.

Comment: I think You're trying to add book for only one user, am i correct? But for an HABTM association you need to assign it multiple users

Comment: @Anilkumar, yes you are correct. So you are saying that User-model should have hasMany-relations to books_users?

Comment: let me illustrate with an example: 
In your view file you should have list of books where user can select them and saving the record will obviously make entries into books_users table

Answer (score 1):

You are quite confused with HABTM...

Please refer to [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-habtm) when you are in doubt.

In there you have an example of how the saved array should be

```
Array
(
    [Recipe] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42
        )
    [Tag] => Array
        (
            [name] => Italian
        )
)
```

So, transforming that to what you want to do, you need to save this array...

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => $this->Auth->user('user_id')
        )
    [Book] => Array
        (
            [name] => book,
            /* your other book stuff */
        )
)
```

and do a simple `$this->save($suggestedBySOArray)` to save the relation.

The link to the docs have more examples on how to save data to HABTM if you need more examples.

**EDIT:**

I'll add a bit more code to help you get on the right path. Now, *I'm assuming* things* in this example since your question doesn't say:
1) you are *creating* a new book, not updating a relation between an existing user with and existing book.
2) you are just adding one book, not many

```
$this->Book->create();

 //what did you intent to do with this piece of code btw? you don't have a "book_user_id" column anywhere
//$this->request->data['Book']['book_user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('user_id');

$data = $this->request->data;

if (!$data['Book']['book_img']['name']) {
    unset($data['Book']['book_img']);
}

$data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('user_id');

if ($this->Book->save($data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The book has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The book could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
```

That ought to do it.

Now, please, read the docs for anything further, it's got examples and everything.

Also, if what @Anilkumar suspected what correct ("You're trying to add book for only one user"), go with hasMany instead of HABTM.

Comment: can you help me creating this array. I cant seem to a grip on it :(

Comment: How about this: $test = array('User' => $this->Auth->user('user_id'), 'Book' => $data);

Comment: No records in books_users still :(

Comment: what does ´pr($test)´ output?

Comment: I've added the result in my question

Comment: So... your not doing it like the example: ` $test = array('User' => $this->Auth->user('user_id'), 'Book' => $data); ` is not ` $test = array('User' => array('id' => $this->Auth->user('user_id')), 'Book' => $data); `. It has to be exactly like the example or bad things happen. I'll update the answer with one more example to help you, but be sure you debug everything before panicking :)

Comment: Hi again @Nunser, I've being taking a more manual (but working) approach to this instead. Thanks a lot for your time and patience! :)

Comment: @JesperBaungårdBruunHansen I'm glad you got it working, even if it's a more manual approach. To leave things resolved here, could you post your own answer and accept it, accept other answer, or delete the question if you think that the question and the answer is not going to help anyone else?